# Filter CoreData entity with array of strings

Tags: search, core-data, uitextfield, nspredicate, contains

I have a problem. User enters a text on a `UITextField`, for example: "word sentence". Now, when I filter CoreData entity I do this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@ ", text];
```

But results returned contains entire text "word sentence", but I want do a search for every word. Is it possible with CoreData?

Comment: split the predicate with OR...

Comment: e.g. `[title CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR title CONTAINS[cd] %@, text1, text2]` where `text1` is the first term and `text2` is the second. This predicate could be also created dynamically. I mean, based ont the text the user writes.

Comment: Do not use `[cd]` for strings since performance will be affected.

Comment: Finally, I used nNSCompoundPredicate. Thanks!

Comment: I added my comment as a reply. Please mark it as correct if this does work for you. ;) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in my comment you could split the predicate with `OR` (through a compound predicate). For example.

`[title CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR title CONTAINS[cd] %@, text1, text2]`

where `text1` is the first term and `text2` is the second. This predicate could be also created dynamically. I mean, based on text the user inserts.

If you use `cd` the research could be affected (perfomance will be better without it).